# UnEven Behaviour of UIView when setHidden

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I've created 5 UIView dynamically, which consists of one UILabel and one UIButton each. When I click button, the UIView will setHidden. But it works only on one not other four uiviews.

```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController 
   {
         NSMutableArray *newViews;

   }
   @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *welcome;
   @property(nonatomic,retain)CustomView *custom;
      -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
    @end



   - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSString *name=@"string of length";

       int length=[name length];

      newViews = [NSMutableArray array];

      NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"cricket",          @"golf",@"wrestling", @"FootBall is good game", nil];

int yAxis=44;

int lengthOfArray=[myArray count];

for(int a=0; a<=lengthOfArray; a++){
    self.custom= [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, yAxis, 100, 44)];
        yAxis=yAxis+50;
        NSLog(@"yaxis is %i",yAxis);
        self.custom.tag=200+a;

    [newViews addObject:self.custom];
    self.custom.Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, length+70, 30)];
    self.custom.button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85,10,12,10)];
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_droparrow.png"];
    [self.custom.button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.custom.button addTarget:self                       action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

     self.custom.button.tag=self.custom.button.tag+a;

    self.custom.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    custom.Label.text=@"welcome";

    custom.Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.custom addSubview:self.custom.button];

    [self.custom addSubview:custom.Label];

    [self.view addSubview:self.custom];
}

   [self.custom.button addTarget:self                       action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 }

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
 {
     [self.custom setHidden:YES];

  }

   @end
```

Kindly help me. I am new in iOS development. I need here to create UIView with differrnt reference and that reference assign to UIButton to close that particular UIView but I could not get result out.

Comment: You are only hiding `self.custom` which ends up pointing only to the last `CustomView` you create.

Comment: yes that was problem how i create reference for each uivew that was problem yet live...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use properties, you will have to make a property for each view. Instead, if you want to create them dynamicaly you could store the references to each view in an array.

The next you should know/do is to add a tag to each button. A tag is just a number, which in this case should reference to its position in the Array.

Then based on the button tag (that you can retrieve from the sender) you can retrieve the proper view/button from the array and change the Hidden property on it.

For example (pseudo code/this wont compile):

Creating the views array

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *views;

In View did load create the views

```
views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int nrOfViews = 5;

for(int a=0; a<=nrOfViews; a++){
   UIView *view = create UIView here.
   UIButton *button = create button here.
   [view addSubView: button];
   [button setTag: a];
   [views addObject: view];
}
```

reference to the view through the pointer retained in the array, find the right one based on the button tag.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
   UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex: sender.tag]; //using the button tag to identify the right view.
   [view setHidden: yes];

}
```

Comment: can you plz help me. now i need to create uiview that must be the same size of uilable that is subview of that view.

Comment: @khaskheli_ayaz You should post a new question for that I think, including the code you already have for that.

Comment: sir i posted new question for that, i hope you will give good suggestion. and i will be thankful and appreciate as well..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UISegmentedControl` along with number of xib for each `UIView`.

- In each `UIView` you can place the required `UIControls` and link the same.
- In the delegate method of `SegmentedControl 'indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender'` on each index remove the earlier `UIView` and add the required UIView.

In the main header file add the `IBOutlet` for each `UIView`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
```

In .m file in the delegate method 'indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl'

```
- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    NSUInteger index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (UISegmentedControlNoSegment != index) {

        if (currentIndex == index) {
            return;
        }

        currentIndex = index;
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                {
                    [self.previousView removeFromSuperview];
                    [self.view addSubview:view1];
                    self.previousView = view1;
                }
                break;

             case 1:
                {
                    [self.previousView removeFromSuperview];
                    [self.view addSubview:view2];
                    self.previousView = view2;
                }
                break;
        }
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void) buttonPressed: (UIButton*) sender
{
    UIView* view = sender.superview;
    view.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: sir i need to create uiview according to the uilabel size can you help me with this regard...

Answer (score -1):

You need to make some changes as follows

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UILabel *welcome; // new arc code
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIView *custom; // new arc code 

self.custom = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, yAxis, 100, 44)];
```